# Stop videos from readjusting phone volume on play

Tags: video, volume-control, volume, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Samsung Galaxy S10e

If the volume is set to vibrate (all the way down), then a video is started, the video will automatically bring the volume back up to about 70%. How can this behavior be disabled? I would like to watch videos on mute without getting a blast of noise at the first second while I scramble to get the volume back down again.

Comment: Use a different video player app? Nobody forces you to use the one that is installed by default.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a single media player is in charge of running videos across all apps? If this is the case, how can I find out the name of this player? I'm new to Android.

Comment: On Android, [there are separate volume channels](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9082609) for ringtone+notification, media, alarm. etc. When you set the volume to vibrate, most likely it only sets ringtone+notification to vibrate but doesn't change other volume channels. You possibly need to manually adjust the volume for media to 0 too.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Thanks @AndrewT.

Comment: @A__ No Android has no central video player. And you never mentioned in your question that you are talking about multiple apps. An answer can only be as good as the question...

Comment: You're right Robert, I wasn't aware that would be assumed. It's my fault. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, [there are separate volume channels](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9082609) for ringtone + notification, media, alarm. etc.

> - Media volume: Music, videos, games, other media
> - Call volume: Volume of the other person during a call
> - Ring volume: Phone calls, notifications
> - Alarm volume

When you set the volume to vibrate, most likely it only sets ringtone + notification to vibrate but doesn't change other volume channels. This is because [pressing the volume up/down button will only change the volume for the active audio stream](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones).

> By default, pressing the volume control modifies the volume of the active audio stream. If your app isn't currently playing anything, hitting the volume keys adjusts the music volume (or the ringer volume before Android 9).

To watch the video on mute, you need to manually adjust the volume for media to 0 too.